# Do white walkers swim?

Tags: game-of-thrones

One thing I don't understand is that if the white walkers and the dead cannot swim, how did they manage to

> resurface the dragon from water?

Comment: @Politank I think that's missing the substance of the question. I take it as "White walkers can't swim right? So given that how do they retrieve the dragon?". The first bit of the question is just saying "feel free to say my premise is wrong" the dragon is the important bit

Comment: @user20310 Check out [these](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/167688/44480) [answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/168340/44480). I stand by my close vote.

Comment: @politank really if you have to hunt around for a side point in a secondary answer it's a reference at best. But the new duplicate is much much better so I'm happy